# Не могу получить доступ к данным в MySQL из программы на Go

Tags: mysql, golang

При попытке получить доступ к существующей базе данных для работы с информацией в таблицах использую такую программу на Go

```
package main 
import (
"database/sql"
"fmt"
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
func main() {
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:paswword@tcp (000.000.000.000:3306)/basename")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
    fmt.Println("==>")
}
fmt.Println("Открыли соединение с базой")
defer db.Close()
// Open doesn't open a connection. Validate DSN data:
err = db.Ping()
fmt.Println("Что с пингом?")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic 
    fmt.Println("Однако Ping-паника...", err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("Validate DSN data: Yes!")
}
```

В результате получаю сообщение `panic: MySQL server does not support required protocol 41+` MySQL версии 4. База данных рабочая, ведется давно... Подскажите каким образом можно решить эту проблему? Может быть нужно использовать не `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, а какие-то другие программы для доступа к базе?

Comment: Посмотрите точнее версию базы. В readme библиотеки написано что требуется mtsql 4.1+. MySQL (4.1+), MariaDB, Percona Server, Google CloudSQL or Sphinx (2.2.3+)

Comment: @Bleser, уточнил версию базы, вот такой ответ `Server version 4.0.27` соответственно, поскольку в readme библиотеки написано что требуется mtsql 4.1+., то работать она видимо не будет. А какая будет? Может вы знаете или сталкивались с такой проблемой? Как ее решить?

Comment: Аналогичная история и с библиотекой `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` то же же самое сообщение об ошибке `MySQL server does not support required protocol 41+`

Comment: Эта библиотека `https://github.com/Philio/GoMySQL`вроде как может работать с нужной версией СУБД - "Implements the MySQL protocol version 4.0- and 4.1+" но при попытке загрузить ее вылезает огромное количество ошибок... скорее всего написана на старой версии go. Поиски решения продолжаются...

Comment: Попробуйте https://github.com/yuuki/go-sql-driver-mysql, по описанию это форк для работы с mysql 4.0

Comment: Попробовал, но нужного результата не получил... Только следующие сообщения: `[mysql] 2018/04/08 21:28:40 packets.go:32: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2018/04/08 21:28:40 packets.go:32: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2018/04/08 21:28:40 packets.go:32: unexpected EOF
Ответ db.Ping:
panic: driver: bad connection` может быть я что-то принципиальное неправильно делаю? Например. import... `"database/sql"
 "fmt"
 _ "github.com/yuuki/go-sql-driver-mysql"` или `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:paswword@tcp (000.000.000.000:3306)/basename")` Никак не могу разобраться.

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать ODBC драйвер.
Коннектор для вашей системы можно скачать (возможно он уже установлен): https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html
В google есть несколько реализаций интерфейсов для связи с ODBC, но так как я с ним не работал, пробуйте сами.